# C# Remove file extension from string list

Tags: c#

What my program does is basically it lists file names (including it's extension) from a directory into a listbox. It then has a sorting function which sorts the list strings into alphabetical order.

Lastly it has a binary search function that allows the users to input any string which the program will then compare and display the matched results into a listbox.

Now, all these functions work perfectly however I can't seem to remove the extension off of a file name after a search.

For example in the scanning and sorting part it lists the file names as: filename.mp3

Now, what I want it do when the searching button is clicked is to remove the file extension and display just the filename.

```
    private void buttonSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        listBox1.Items.Clear();

        string searchString = textBoxSearchPath.Text;


        int index = BinarySearch(list1, 0, list1.Count, searchString);

        for (int n = index; n < list1.Count; n++)
        {
            //Removes file extension from last decimal point ''not working''
            int i = list1[n].LastIndexOf(".");
            if (i > 0)
                list1[n].Substring(0, i);

            // Adds items to list
            if (list1[n].IndexOf(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != 0) break; 
            listBox1.Items.Add(list1[n]);
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Done");
    }
```

Comment: Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement that in my code (above) as I've already processed the file names in the string list

Comment: You can use the static operations in the System.IO.Path class to deal with extensions.  GetExtension() or GetFileNameWithoutExtension() comes to mind

Also you should always use { } for your if blocks even if there's only one line ... your one if block is different than the second one ......

Comment: What do you not understand exactly? Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()  is quite straightforward.

Comment: you didn't assign the sub string value like this list1[n] = list1[n].Substring(0, i);

Comment: @Pandian I can't believe I overlooked that! It worked! :D Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Substring` method returns a new fresh copy of the string, copied from the source one. If you want to "cut the extension off", then you must fetch what Substring returns and store it somewhere, i.e.:

```
int i = list1[n].LastIndexOf(".");
if (i > 0)
    list1[n] = list1[n].Substring(0, i);
```

However, this is quite odd way to remove an extension.

Firstly, use of `Substring(0,idx)` is odd, as there's a [`Remove(idx)`(link)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/9ad138yc.aspx) which does exactly that:

```
int i = list1[n].LastIndexOf(".");
if (i > 0)
    list1[n] = list1[n].Remove(i);
```

But, sencondly, there's even better way of doing it: the `System.IO.Path` class provides you with a set of well written static methods that, for example, remove the extension (edit: this is what L-Three suggested in comments), with full handling of dots and etc:

```
var str = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("myfile.txt"); // == "myfile"
```

See [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx)

It still returns a copy and you still have to store the result somewhere!

```
list1[n] = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension( list1[n] );
```

Comment: To anyone who negatively-scored this reply: please attach a comment next time, I really curios why. Should I add even more explanations or examples, or too "tl;dr" maybe? heh. Sorry, I'm really curious:)

Comment: @user2257583: no prob, common thing when moving from C++ mutable strings or Ruby's gsub!() :)

Comment: use Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension. That's the beauty of dot net.

Comment: "var str = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("myfile.txt")"; This's so awesome :)

Answer (score 6):

C# is so easy that if something takes more than 2 minutes, [there probably is a method for it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx) in the Framework.

Answer (score 3):

Try like below ite will help you....

Description : [Filename without Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx)

```
        listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(list1[n]));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Use Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension method. Quite easy I guess.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how you've implemented your directory searching, but you can leverage LINQ to your advantage in these situations for clean, easy to read code:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"\\PathToFiles")
            .Select(f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f));
```

If you're using .NET 4.0, Enumerate files seems to be a superior choice over GetFiles.  However it also sounds like you want to get both the full file path and the file name without extension.  Here's how you could create a Dictionary so you'd eliminate looping through the collection twice:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"\\PathToFiles")
            .ToDictionary(f => f, n => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(n));
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this if you don't have a file path, just a file Name

```
string filePath = (@"D:/" + fileName);
string withoutExtension = Path.getFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
```